# jMeter timers - loop delays

Tags: jmeter

I have the following scenario to emulate in jMeter:
100 users logging in once and doing search every 30 secs, with think time 5 secs.
 
How do I implement this?

Right now I have something like this:

```
ThreadGroup(100usrs)
+-- OnceOnlyController(LogIn)
+-- LoopControler(Search)
+-- Timer(5s)
```

But I have no idea how to do the 30 secs delay between the Search instances.
Is it even possible or do I have to use some workaround?
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have a fixed delay between the search samples whatever response time of the Sample is then Orkito solution is not the right one.

His solution will add a 30 s delay before the search sample, so if search takes more time than expected your request will run each 30s + Time taken by search sample.

If you want to have a fixed delay between the search samples whatever response time of the Sample then solution is described here:

- http://blog.milamberspace.net/index.php/2008/08/15/jmeter-fixer-la-duree-de-repetition-dune-requete-87.html

It's in french but there are screenshots and translation service should do the job.

Another important point to note:

> Note that timers are processed before each sampler in the scope in which they are found; if there are several timers in the same scope, all the timers will be processed before each sampler.
>   Timers are only processed in conjunction with a sampler. A timer which is not in the same scope as a sampler will not be processed at all.
>   To apply a timer to a single sampler, add the timer as a child element of the sampler. The timer will be applied before the sampler is executed. To apply a timer after a sampler, either add it to the next sampler, or add it as the child of a Test Action Sampler.

Comment: I ended up using a Test Action with 30s pause. What is the difference between simple pause Test Action and the solution given on the webpage?

Comment: With your solution you don't vary pause time depending on response time while webpage proposes a variable pause time to make a request every 30s. With a test action note thzt if you use transaction controller tpu won't be able to exclude time taken from response time.

Comment: I am actually more interested in request every 45s irregardless of response times, so according to your explanation pure Test Action should be ok. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I think you have to add another timer as a child of LoopController: Timer(30). Your search requests are under the scope of that controller and your 30s timer should be there too.

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers

Answer (score 1):

Instead of use Constant Timer you should use **Constant Throughput Timer**, because this timer considers also Sample time(that is the execution time of each sample).
If you use a Constant Timer, you will have delay piled from each sample execution

Answer (score 0):

If someone still having some troubles and wants an easy way, you can just add Constant Timer in one of the HTTP Request of the thread.

As you can see in the image you can have a controller with a bunch of requests, and then a second one inside a loop. In the second you can set a timer inside the first request, so it will delay the launch of this one without affecting the others.
[Demo image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75KpQ.png)