# Apache Jmeter-How to apply wait for page load?

Tags: apache, jmeter, tomcat6

After recording the login page script  and playback.its giving warning and not allow to login in application..

I have to use wait command for waiting few second for doing all process ..

How can i use wait command for page load

Comment: possible duplicate of [jMeter timers - loop delays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528608/jmeter-timers-loop-delays)

Answer (score 0):

Following approaches are possible:

1) using Test Action (Add >> Sampler >> Test Action).
Its advantage is the following: interval value can be passed as parameter that can be obtained either from file, either generated.

2) One can also look through [fixed delay between the search samples](http://blog.milamberspace.net/index.php/2008/08/15/jmeter-fixer-la-duree-de-repetition-dune-requete-87.html) whatever response time of the Sample

Actual difference between first approach and second one:
you don't vary pause time depending on response time while webpage proposes a variable pause time to make a request every 30s. With a test action note that if you use transaction controller you won't be able to exclude time taken from response time.

Also one should remember that timers are processed before each sampler in the scope in which they are found; if there are several timers in the same scope, all the timers will be processed before each sampler. 
Pay attention to [Execution order](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html) (section 4.9) of Timers in jMeter.

[Throughput Constant Timer usage](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) example.